# (C# - GridView) Open hidden FileUpload Dialogue on LinkButton_Click in Code Behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, file-upload

I created this `LinkButton` **inside** my `GridView`:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonOpenFile" CssClass="fa fa-upload" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButtonOpenFile_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

**Outside** my GridView i've created a `FileUpload`:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Visible="false"/>
```

I tried to get my `LinkButton` to open the `FileUpload` Dialogue with Javascript(*both server and clientside*). Non of them Trigger. 
Is it because my `LinkButton` is in my `GridView`?

Example on what i've tried:;

***ClientSide & ServerSide JS:***

```
function openFile(){
        $("#FileUpload1").click();
        }
```

**and**

```
protected void LinkButtonOpenFile_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "openFile()", true);
    }
```

Any Suggestions on How to fix this issue?

**Update: Also tried this**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonOpenFile" CssClass="fa fa-upload" runat="server" OnClientClick="openFile();return false;"></asp:LinkButton>
```

JS:

```
 function openFile(){
    $("#FileUpload1").click();
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just found this Code Snippet which helped me a lot:

In your html do:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <span class="file"><!--diesen span kannst du stylen und ist dann anklickbar-->
      Anhänge auswählen
      <input type="file" />
    </span>
  </body>

</html>
```

Add this to your css:

```
.file {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.file input[type=file] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: white;
    cursor: inherit;
    display: block;
}
```

And you are good to go :-)